# Accessing a data structure in C in threadsafe manner

Tags: c, multithreading

I am new to multi-threading with C and working on a project where I have a global data structure shared between serveral threads, many threads write to it and a few read from it. I intend to create a thread-safe mechanism to access the data structure.
I have thought of an approach but intend to ask if that is the right way.
So, for the sake of simplicity I will assume that there is only one paramameter( lets call it speed ) which is accessed by several threads:
I have done the following so far:

### GlobalData.h

```
int GetData();
void SetData();
```

---

### GlobalData.c

```
#include "GlobalData.h"

static int speed;
static mutex mut;

void SetSpeed( int inSpeed )
{
    mut.lock();
    speed = inSpeed;
    mut.unlock();
}
int GetSpeed()
{
    mut.lock();
    int val = speed;
    mut.unlock();
    return val;
}
```

---

Now all the threads are forced to use the API given in GlobalData.h and it is internally threadsafe.
Do you think this is a right approach?

Comment: With the exception of `GetSpeed` returning the wrong variable, it looks good.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Oops, I did not intend to return the wriong value! Thanks for having a look! :)

Comment: There is no such thing as "the right approach". It either works or it doesn't. Do you have a specific concern in mind? Any particular reason you think this might not work, besides that gnawing feeling in the back of your head telling you you forgot something, that everyone gets when  working with threads?

Comment: That's an approach. You can also just use the C standard libraries [atomic facilities](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic). An atomic int will not be any worse that your locking version, but it may end up being lock free.

Comment: @MadPhysicist: I believe it was the later, also I wanted to know if there is some other approaches I can look into, as StoryTeller pointed to the atomic library! Thanks you guys!

Comment: @MadPhysicist "besides that gnawing feeling in the back of your head telling you you forgot something, that everyone gets when working with threads?" I didn't realize that everyone has it. So, I'm not alone. I'm very happy to hear (i.e. read) this.

Comment: @Scheff. "Everyone" might be an overstatement, but certainly the majority of people I've mentioned it to. Imagine trying to debug OP's original version (which had `return speed` instead of `return val`) for some weird case that popped at error once every couple of years.

Comment: @PRIME. That makes your question much better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com. I believe you are off topic for SO.

Comment: @MadPhysicist: Thanks for introducing me to codereview stackexchange :). Indeed this question is a better suit for the review forum. But I am afraid it is not possible to move it there now. I will use code review stackexchange for future questions such as this.

Comment: @PRIME. You make a new question there and delete the one here. Why is that impossible?

Comment: While the overall plan of encapsulating access into one interface is good, a detailed design suggestion is not possible without a full spec for your system.  For example, is a backing store to be kept up-to-date?  Are all reads/writes so simple as you suggest, or may they take some extended time, (eg. the data is actually on another box with long latency on the access)?  Are there any dependencies between data items, (eg. if there is another item 'direction', and a thread wishes to write a velocity change, then changing 'speed' and 'direction' separately results in a window of invalid data)?

Comment: @MadPhysicist: Moving is not possible, creating a new and deleting this one is indeed possible, although I belive it is counter intiutive, considering people have already spent some effort answering it here.

Comment: @PRIME. I don't see any answers, not even  deleted ones.

Comment: @MadPhysicist: Oh! I mean answers which came as comments. Not the actual answers. Later on I will consolidate the points which came as comments and move it to code review forum.

Comment: @MartinJames: Thanks for having a look,The work is for an embedded device which runs on threadX,There are a few threads which read values from some sesors and after some computation set values(absolute new values or an increment on the previous values)in a global data structure which is like the Model for my complete system,Some threads periodically read value from this structure for display or broadcasting purpose.I am just starting with it yet but I understand your remark on the dependency of some attributes(velocity/speed) example,Indeed something to take care.Thanks!